# Expected value of a random variable in a piecewise function

Tags: expected-value, piecewise-continuity, cumulative-distribution-functions

I need to find the expected value of the following function

$$
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0 &\text{ if }\:x < 0 \\
 x^{3} &\text{ if }\: 0\leq x < 1\\
 1 &\text{ if }\: x\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

I use the formula $E[x] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\cdot f(x)dx \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}x\cdot x^3dx\, +\, \int_{1}^{\infty} x\cdot dx$

The second integral on the interval $[1, \infty]$ is infinity, which is definitely off.

But I am not sure about the right approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=F'(x)=3x^2$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

$E(X)=\int_0^1 3x^3dx=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Can you provide more details? When I integrate $\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot x^3dx$, I got $\frac{x^{5}}{5}$, and how can $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, when $f(x) = 1$ when $x\geq1$ ?

Comment: Ok I see now. I misinterpreted $F(x)$ as $f(x)$

Comment: The formula you are using is wrong.  You need to use the density function $f(x)=F'(x)$, NOT the distribution function $F(x)$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I need to consolidate my knowledge on this part.